# How to access property of a view controller from another class

Tags: objective-c, properties

My project is very simple. I made it to try and understand how classes communicate with each other. It has just one view controller with a button.

Here are the View Controller files

```
//ViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *theButton;

@property int clickCount;

- (IBAction)basicAction:(id)sender;

@end



//ViewController.m

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.clickCount = 0;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (IBAction)basicAction:(id)sender {

    self.clickCount ++;
    NSLog(@"Click count now = %d", self.clickCount);

}
@end
```

So, when you click the button we see the count go up. I have created a new class called AnotherClass that has one method. Here are the files:

```
1 //AnotherClass.h
2
3 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
4 #import"ViewController.h"
5 
6 @interface AnotherClass : NSObject
7
8
9 -(void)theMethod;
10
11 @end
12
13 //AnotherClass.m
14
15 #import "AnotherClass.h"
16
17 @implementation AnotherClass
18
19 -(void)theMethod{
20   if(ViewController.clickCount < 5){             
21 do something...
22 } else { do something else...}
23 }
24   @end
```

So super simple stuff. But it's not recognising the property clickCount from the ViewController class on line 20. It does on it's own h file when it's accessed through "self." notation. I have imported ViewController.h in the header and as far as I know that's all you need to do to access other classes properties and methods. Is that right?

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you aren't getting a value is because `AnotherClass` is trying to access `clickCount` as a static instead of an instance variable. You will want to get an instance of `ViewController` by some method in `AnotherClass`. Assuming you set up ViewController as the root view controller you can use the code below to get the click count.

```
ViewController *controller = (ViewController*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
if (controller.clickCount < 5) {
    ...
}
```

Note that you must cast UIViewController to ViewController first and then read clickCount from the controller variable.

Comment: It's possible the code isn't executing. You need to call `theMethod` from somewhere. Setting a breakpoint may help before testing you code. Click in the left hand gutter, to the left of the line of code you want to stop, to set a breakpoint. Then when you run it will stop at that point. If it doesn't stop that should tell you the code never executes.